# bash script to write content into file. File content requires bash variables. How to do that?

Tags: bash, unix, file-io

The following is a piece of content my bash script will write into the nginx configuration file.

```
WEBAPP=example.com
APPFOLDER=abcapp
CONFFILENAME=abc.conf

read -r -d '' FILECONTENT <<'ENDFILECONTENT'
server {
        listen 80;
        client_max_body_size 2M;
        server_name $WEBAPP;
        root /var/virtual/stage.$WEBAPP/current/src/$APPFOLDER/webroot;
}

ENDFILECONTENT
echo "$FILECONTENT" > /etc/nginx/sites-available/$CONFFILENAME
```

The code works successfully to write the content inside `/etc/nginx/sites-available/abc.conf`.

However, I have two bash variables in `$WEBAPP` and `$APPFOLDER`. They are manifested exactly like that inside the file instead of `example.com` and `abcapp` which is what I intended.

How do I make the script work as intended?

Comment: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html

Comment: Do yourself a favor and forget `read` exists. It is rarely necessary and often misused.

Answer (score 5):

bash allows newlines in quoted strings. It does parameter replacement (that is, `$FOO` gets replaced with the value of `FOO`) inside double-quoted strings (`"$FOO"`) but not inside single-quoted strings (`'$FOO'`).

So you could just do this:

```
FILECONTENT="server {
        listen 80;
        client_max_body_size 2M;
        server_name $WEBAPP;
        root /var/virtual/stage.$WEBAPP/current/src/$APPFOLDER/webroot;
}"
echo "$FILECONTENT" > /etc/nginx/sites-available/$CONFFILENAME
```

You don't really need the `FILECONTENT` parameter, since you could just copy directly to the file:

```
cat >/etc/nginx/sites-available/$CONFFILENAME <<ENDOFCONTENT
server {
        listen 80;
        client_max_body_size 2M;
        server_name $WEBAPP;
        root /var/virtual/stage.$WEBAPP/current/src/$APPFOLDER/webroot;
}
ENDOFCONTENT
```

In the second example, using `<<ENDOFCONTENT` indicates that the `$VAR`s should be replaced with their values `<<'ENDOFCONTENT'` would prevent the parameter replacement.

Comment: Do you mean `cat` instead of `cp` in your second example? On my machine, `cat > bar <<< foo` works, but `cp > bar <<< foo` doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually deliberately turning off parameter subsitution by enclosing `'ENDFILECONTENT'` in quotes. See this excerpt from example 19-7 of [the advanced Bash scripting guide on Heredocs](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html), slightly reformatted:

```
# No parameter substitution when the "limit string" is quoted or escaped.
# Either of the following at the head of the here document would have
# the same effect.
#
# cat <<"Endofmessage"
# cat <<\Endofmessage
```

Remove the single quotes around `'ENDFILECONTENT'` and BASH will replace the variables as expected.